# Java: Is this proper behavior of singleton class used to save basic JDK log file?

Tags: java, logging, error-handling

I created the below wrapper for a singleton logger class so that I can log exceptions from any file and/or class. My inspiration comes from here: [Logging to one file from multiple java files](http://www.coderanch.com/t/411562/java/java/Logging-one-file-multiple-java)

I'm new to java and this is my first use of attempting to log exceptions to a file. While the following code does work, I noticed a few quirks I wanted to ask whether or not they were "normal behavior" or whether a workaround exists.

(1) Once the log file is created and has been written to with exceptions, if I edit the log file (e.g. remove some lines of text) then the log file is never written again from that moment forward. The web server needs to restart the domain associated with the web application before the log file is written to again. Is this normal? Ideally, I would like to retain only relevant errors in the log file, and delete the irrelevant ones, without needing to restart the web application's domain in the web server.

(2) If I delete the log file, then later an exception occurs in the java program(s), the log file does not get created again, and the exception is lost. Again, the web server needs to restart the domain associated with the web application before a new log file is created. Is this normal, or is there a workaround somehow by editing the below code? Ideally, I'd like to be able to delete the log file at any time and have the application create a new one.

Again, I'm new here so feel free to point out of the above intentions are bad design, etc.

------code follows------

Here's the file: LoggerWrapper.java

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;   
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;  
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class LoggerWrapper {
public static final Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("Test");
private static LoggerWrapper instance = null;  

 public static LoggerWrapper getInstance() {  
    if(instance == null) {  
        prepareLogger();  
        instance = new LoggerWrapper ();  
    }  
    return instance;  
 }  

private static void prepareLogger() {
try {
   FileHandler myFileHandler = new FileHandler("/path/to/myLogFile.log", true);  
   myFileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());  
   myLogger.addHandler(myFileHandler);  
   myLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);  
   myLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
}    
}
```

To call the above code in a different file or class, issue these lines (for example):

```
LoggerWrapper loggerWrapper = LoggerWrapper.getInstance();
...
loggerWrapper.myLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "some text here"+e.fillInStackTrace());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is running on linux? When you open the file it's pointing to a reference to that file. When you delete the file the reference is gone, but since you saved the reference in a static variable, your code is now holding a file handle that points to nothing. Instead you should do something like

```
cat /dev/null > file
```

Which will just copy nothing over the file without changing the actual inode that the file points to.

Comment: Yes on Linux (CentOS). Is "file" above my log file name? I'm not sure if your `cat /dev/null > file` is in response to the first or second question above (or both). That is, what will that line of code typed into the command line do (e.g. what problem does it solve)?

Comment: Yes, that's the logfile. I was replying to #2. I assume the problem you are seeing with #1 is similar. If you type the above command it will empty the contents of your logfile without deleting it, so existing handles on the file (like in your code) will keep working.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I realize one can also use your above code idea to solve #1. Just copy the log file into a new file (e.g. newFile), edit this new file as desired, then do a `cat newFile > file`. Now new updates to the pre-existing log file (e.g. file) will take place as usual. I tested it and it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to go to all of this trouble with logging.  The log handler (and all of the alternatives, like logback, log4j) or a wrapper framework like Commons Logging or slf4j will do almost all of this work for you.

The most widely accepted method of using logging is to use a wrapper system (slf4j is very popular) and then just include the log class as a private static attribute of each class.  Then you can do all of the configuration either with a separate program, or you can have configuration files that will set everything up for you.

If you want to set up your logging system in code (not the way I would do it, but you can...), do it in a static initializer that you know will load relatively early.  Once the logging system has it's information, it won't need to be configured again.

Comment: Do you know if SLF4J solves the above 2 issues? Or are you just saying that SFL4J is more popular than `java.util.logging`?

Comment: No, I was just pointing out that your design was unnecessarily complex.  You did mention you wanted design tips, so I wanted to offer a few.

slf4j is a decorator framework.  It allows you to "log" and then have the system administrator provide a logging framework that is best for them.  It breaks apart your code (above) in to development and deployment.

Glad you found the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142465/log4j-stops-logging-in-a-filefile-appenders-when-i-open-edit-the-file) ?

It may have to do with your editor/os. The poster from the linked question had a similar problem with log4j.

As the other answer states, to clear out the log file w/o disturbing the handler:

```
cat /dev/null > file.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the link RajChola! I hadn't seen it, and so you've saved me hours of effort to get LOG4J running only to discover it has the same problems.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you just don't edit the files! And don't delete them!

HAHAHAHA, that would be an ace solution, no?

You should really use the open source logging (i've always liked log4j - most IB use that, or slf4j) that has been suggested by Jonathan - it is the standard way to do logging, nobody really does logging like you're  doing it. At least, not that I am aware.

Ok, that said - and I do not know linux at all, in any shape or form - it sounds like, as Rick suggests, whatever you are pointing to disappears when you edit/delete the file. So, in pseudo-code (because, and i am sorry for this - as i indicated, i use windows so cannot test):

```
public class LoggerWrapper {
    *private* FileHandler myFileHandler;
    *private* static final Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("Test");
    private static LoggerWrapper instance = null;  

    /*
      here check if the file you're using has been changed! If so, re-do the file setting
    */
    public void log(Level level, String message){
        //argh you are on your own here. I don't know how to *check* the file being used by the file handler...
        //you know what? you can just do this (but it isn't too clean)
        myLogger.removeFileHandler(myFileHandler);
        myFileHandler = new FileHandler("/path/to/myLogFile.log", true); 
        myLogger.addHandler(myFileHandler);
        myLogger.log(level,message);     
    }  

    private static void prepareLogger() {
        try {
            //don't shadow the myFileHandler by accident!
            myFileHandler = new FileHandler("/path/to/myLogFile.log", true); 

...
```

of course, that just resets the file handler every time you log. And you won't log with the command:

```
loggerWrapper.myLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "some text here"+e.fillInStackTrace());
```

but with

```
loggerWrapper.log(Level.SEVERE, "some text here"+e.fillInStackTrace());
```

Or just use open source logging (log4j!) and be happy! There might be some way to check if the file is lost - oh! maybe  check the isLoggable method? I don't know if that will pick up on changed  files... i don't think it does though.

Also, you might need to setErrorManager on your fileHandler - from the looks of things, if the logger cannot, well, log, it sends something to the errorManager. I am unfamiliar with this though, and i might be speaking jibberish.

Comment: log4j has been deprecated by the author. Nobody uses it anymore. Logback is the replacement. Java.util.logging is used by many people and many open source project and sl4j is used to bridge them all together.

Comment: ? nobody uses it! Good grief. Deprecated? bulldust. Where are you getting your information from? Here is my source: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html

Comment: Look at the first sentence on the logback page: http://logback.qos.ch/ Ceki wrote SLF4J and logback as replacements.

Comment: I shouldn't say "nobody" uses it anymore, but I certainly wouldn't use it on a new project